Python: Wrap a text with ANSI escape sequences in it
In the wrap function from the textwrap module, there’s no way to exclude ANSI escape sequences or other patterns when wrapping text.
I want to extend the function with the parameter exclude of type string. The argument should be a regular expression that is excluded when wrapping the text but remains in the output.
Does anyone have a solution?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
